# string editing in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am having a string in that I have getting a tag </p> and I want to append </b> ahead of </p>

```
let str = "<p>A new week-long event is kicking off soon in <a href="/pokemon-go/" data-ref-id="5000-449545">Pokemon Go</a>. Niantic is holding another Adventure Week beginning Tuesday, June 4, and it'll give players a chance to earn extra rewards, catch some rare Rock-types, and even find a couple of new Shiny Pokemon.</p><p>During Adventure Week, Geodude, Rhyhorn, Omanyte, Aron, Lileep, Anorith, and other Rock Pokemon will appear in the wild much more frequently than normal.</p>"
```

I want this string as:

```
let newStr = #"<b><p>A new week-long event is kicking off soon in <a href="/pokemon-go/" data-ref-id="5000-449545">Pokemon Go</a>. Niantic is holding another Adventure Week beginning Tuesday, June 4, and it'll give players a chance to earn extra rewards, catch some rare Rock-types, and even find a couple of new Shiny Pokemon.</p></b><p>During Adventure Week, Geodude, Rhyhorn, Omanyte, Aron, Lileep, Anorith, and other Rock Pokemon will appear in the wild much more frequently than normal.</p>"#
```

Comment: I was thing of this but this will change all my </p> to </p></b> let newString = str(of: "</p>", with: "</p></b>")

Comment: Do you want to change first tag only? Or all occurrences?

Comment: yes only the first tag @arun siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace all occurrences of a string with another string you can use [replacingOccurrences(of:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences). If you want to replace the first occurrence find range of the substring and replace with new substring

```
if let range = str.range(of: "<p>") {
    str.replaceSubrange(range, with: "<b><p>")
}
if let range = str.range(of: "</p>") {
    str.replaceSubrange(range, with: "</b></p>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated due comment** (just first tag) -> See history if you want simpler edition

```
extension String {

    enum TagRange {
        case first
        case last
        case any
    }

    func addingHTMLTag(_ wrapperTag: String, around tagToWrap: String, witchIs tagRange: TagRange = .any) -> String {

        let range: NSRange?
        let regxPattern = "<\(tagToWrap)>(.+?)</\(tagToWrap)>"
        let regx = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regxPattern, options: [])
        let allRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf8.count)

        switch tagRange {
        case .first: range = regx.rangeOfFirstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: allRange)
        case .last: range = regx.matches(in: self, options: [], range: allRange).last?.range
        case .any: range = nil
        }

        if let range = range {
            let openTagged = (self as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "<\(tagToWrap)>", with: "<\(wrapperTag)><\(tagToWrap)>", range: range)


            let offsetRange = NSRange(location: range.location + (wrapperTag.count+2) , length: range.length)

            return (openTagged as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "</\(tagToWrap)>", with: "</\(tagToWrap)></\(wrapperTag)>", range: offsetRange)
        } else {
            let openTagged = replacingOccurrences(of: "<\(tagToWrap)>", with: "<\(wrapperTag)><\(tagToWrap)>")
            return openTagged.replacingOccurrences(of: "</\(tagToWrap)>", with: "</\(tagToWrap)></\(wrapperTag)>")
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let newStr = str.addingHTMLTag("b", around: "p", witchIs: .first)
```

This method also checks **if** the tag you want to wrap around is **valid**. Maybe there is **no closing tag** or **no opening tag** or **invalid opening and closing tags order**. or maybe there is a`<p>` in the text itself! that you don't want to wrap.

Comment: Updated @arunsiva.